# How to get more space in the / partition in this specific case

Tags: partitioning

I have a lot of spare space in my hard disk. But the size of `/` partition is very small. Here is a snap of my partition table in Gparted,

[image]

How can I expand my `/` partition? Step by step description will be helpful.

Comment: I think I would create a new partition in the large unused area, and install Ubuntu there. Possibly move system wide settings (like in the `/etc` directory) over from the old to the new system.

Comment: You can shrink /home then move it right to make room for empty space where you can later grow /. If shrinking /home is not an option, copy the partition into the empty space, then delete original copy (make backup !), and grow /.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a backup of all important files. Just in case you mess up.
- Remove swap. [How can I turn off swap permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440326/how-can-i-turn-off-swap-permanently/440349)

From gparted live session ...

- enlarge `/home/` with the 411Gb unallocated
- shrink `/home/` and create unallocated space at the beginning of `/home/`
- enlarge `/` with the unallocated space

When done ...

- Recreate swap. [How do I add a swap partition after system installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation)

By the way: I myself have used a desktop with size of 10Gb for `/` and never ran out of space. You could also spend a little time investigating why it is growing. Maybe there is something to remove. Or files that should be on `/home/`. Log files that keep growing. Etc. 10Gb is a lot if you refrain yourself from installing anything you see. Also check software center for software you never use anymore. Got mysql installed because you wanted to check how a database works?

Answer (score 0):

what you *could* do, is:
First, move your swap (using Gparted, I think you'll know how to)

then you have two options:
1.  You could either lazy unmount your home folder through the terminal, by typing
- sudo umount -l /dev/sda8
- then refresh the partitions in Gparted,
- move your home folder, and then enlarge your /
I thought I'd heard this should be possible without unmounting, otherwise use the live usb

2. to do the live USB: follow the instructions on the
   [Gparted website](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php)

   - reboot with the USB inserted
   - repeatedly press F9 on startup, select USB in the boot menu and you should be able to do anything you want.
   - move your swap
   - move your home folder
   - resize your root partition
   - don't forget to execute
   - reboot back into linux
   - happy days :)