# System Monitor shows only 1.1GB swap, where as there is 15GB swap

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, swap

I've dual-booted my laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. While installing Ubuntu, I created a swap space of 15GB. My laptop has 8GB RAM. I hadn't noticed earlier, but now that my system is running out of memory, I noticed that System Monitor shows only 1.1GB swap. Turning off swap and turning it on doesn't help either. What is happening here? How can I fix it?

[image: gparted snapshot]

[image: system monitor snapshot]

PS: I don't know if it matters. Initially I had tried to disable swap altogether. I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/440349/775359) and set swappiness to 10. Now I've changed it back to the default value 60.

**Edit1**:
Adding content of `/etc/fstab`

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=3f9f3cd3-acfb-47a8-aff2-fac6a7405e02 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=B827-57AB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
# (identifier)  (location, eg sda5)   (format, eg ext3 or ext4)      (some settings) 
UUID=3a70fe9d-3ffc-4e4e-b7b1-d94f2dbe0bbd   /home    ext4          defaults       0       2
```

Comment: I understand that the current trend is to only use 8GB swap if your computer has GB RAM. What does the command `free` show? Or `swapon -s`?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1265619/edit) to include the line(s) of `/etc/fstab` that include swap.

Comment: In the terminal, run `sudo cat /proc/swaps` and you'll *probably* discover you're using swapfile and not a swap partition. It'll look like `/swapfile` when you run the command. If that's the case, you can use a search engine to find out how to change it.

Comment: Perfect. It worked. Thanks. If you can write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Following [KGIII](https://askubuntu.com/users/453950/kgiii)'s comment, I fixed it as follows

Check if `/swapfile` is being used instead of swap partition

```
$ sudo cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        1158220 0   -2
```

Now, to change swap from using `/swapfile` to partition, I followed [this blog](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-use-swap-file-instead-of-swap.html). Although it does the reverse, the required commands are available.

Turn off `/swapfile`

```
$ sudo swapoff /swapfile
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` file to use swap partition instead of `/swapfile`. Commented existing line and added new line. UUID can be obtained from gparted (right click on swap partition and select `information`)

```
UUID=530e52cc-8a1d-400b-bbde-b47c0246586d none            swap    sw              0       0
# /swapfile                               none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Format the swap partition

```
$ sudo mkswap /dev/nvme0n1p8
```

Set swap to use the partition

```
$ sudo swapon /dev/nvme0n1p8
```